# Merging many different feature classes into one but only taking certain fields from each?

Tags: merge, field-mapping

I'm trying to merge ~50 feature classes into 1.  The problem is, these feature classes have many different fields, and some that i don't want in the final FC.  I can delete the fields one by one manually when the Merge geoprocessing window comes up in the Field Map area, but this really isn't ideal - i just deleted ~400 fields that took over an hour, and then the Merge ended up failing.

There must be an easier way to do this?

Comment: Which software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

you should use dissolve tool. it will merge fearures having same field value The tool has option for dissolve field. selected fields will remain in output and rest will be deleted.